# React Router - When unauthenticated refreshing on plain route pages redirects me to index page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

When a user is authenticated, I can refresh the page and access all the routes through the website or by entering/refreshing the URL. However, when the user is unauthenticated, although the routing through the website works well, refreshing the URL even on plain route pages (non-private) redirects me to index (main page).

I have used [this](https://github.com/BootstrapDash/corona-react-free-admin-template) as the template of my react app and [this](https://github.com/rishipr/mern-auth) for adding authentication to my react app. I have tried these two guides seperately and both work well but somehow in my react app their combination leads to the issue I described above.

Below is the code for my app routes:

```
import React, { Component, lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Spinner from '../app/shared/Spinner';


const MainIndex = lazy(() => import( "./mainpage/Index"));
const TermsIndex = lazy(() => import( "./mainpage/Terms"));
const Dashboardmain = lazy(() => import( "./dashboard/Dashboardmain"));
const Login = lazy(() => import( "./user-pages/Login"));
const Register = lazy(() => import( "./user-pages/Register"));


class AppRoutes extends Component {
  render () {
    return (

        <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />
            <Route exact path="/index" component={ MainIndex } />
            <Route exact path="/terms" component={ TermsIndex } />

            <PrivateRoute exact path="/internal/dashboard" component={ Dashboardmain } />

            <Route exact path="/register" component={ Register } />

          </Switch>
        </Suspense>

    );
  }
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

My app pages look like this - the FullPageLayout is to check if header, footer or sidebar should be added for the page or not:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';
import Navbar from './shared/Navbar';
import Sidebar from './shared/Sidebar';
import Footer from './shared/Footer';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class AppPages extends Component {
  state = {}
  componentDidMount() {
    this.onRouteChanged();
  }

  render () {

    let navbarComponent = !this.state.isFullPageLayout ? <Navbar/> : '';
    let sidebarComponent = !this.state.isFullPageLayout ? <Sidebar/> : '';
    let footerComponent = !this.state.isFullPageLayout ? <Footer/> : '';

    return (
          <div className="container-scroller">
            { sidebarComponent }
            <div className="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
              { navbarComponent }
              <div className="main-panel">
                <div className="content-wrapper">
                  <AppRoutes/>
                </div>
                { footerComponent }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      this.onRouteChanged();
    }
  }

  onRouteChanged() {
    const containment = [];
    const fullPageLayoutRoutes = ['/login', '/register', 
    '/index', '/terms'];

    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.classList.remove('rtl')
    for (var i = 0; i < fullPageLayoutRoutes.length; i++) {
      containment[containment.length] = this.props.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes(fullPageLayoutRoutes[i])
    }
    if (containment.includes(true)) {
        this.setState({isFullPageLayout: true})
        document.querySelector('.page-body-wrapper').classList.add('full-page-wrapper');
    } else {
        this.setState({isFullPageLayout: false})
        document.querySelector('.page-body-wrapper').classList.remove('full-page-wrapper');
    }
  }
}

export default withRouter(AppPages);
```

And my app is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from "../actions/authActions";
import store from "../store";
import AppPages from './AppPages';


// Check for token to keep user logged in
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/login";
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <AppPages/>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried debugging the issue by changing/simplifying things in the router or app part but I don't think the problem is here. I think the problem is somewhere within the reducers or actions.

My store is defined as follows:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()) ||
      compose
  )
);

export default store;
```

My authReducer is defined as:

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "../actions/types";

const isEmpty = require("is-empty");

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My authAction is defined as:

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "./types";

// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login")) // re-direct to login on successful register
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage
      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};
// User loading
export const setUserLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOADING
  };
};
// Log user out
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  // Remove token from local storage
  localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something to do with the order of execution.  The redux state gets erased when you refresh so you need the `store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))` to get called before the `PrivateRoute` tries to render.  It's not obvious to me precisely where it's going wrong because the `if (localStorage.jwtToken) {` block is not `async`, though the `dispatch` might be?

I would recommend setting the `initialState` in `authReducer` to `isAuthenticated: null` and update to either `true` or `false` once you've examined the token.  Right now your `PrivateRoute` only knows two states: authenticated and unauthenticated.  We need it to understand a third which is "I don't know yet".  In your `PrivateRoute` you would render nothing or a loading spinner while `isAutheticated` is `null`.  Don't render the `Redirect` until you have a definite `false`.

Comment: I have set the `initialState` to `isAuthenticated: null` and realised that in my store it is initially null but when I log in as a user it changes to true. However, I think I did not explain myself well. 
My issue is with refreshing non-private pages (i.e. terms page). When I am logged in, I can refresh the URL on the terms page and it loads correctly. But, if I am not logged in, the URL refreshing doesn't work and it takes me back to the login page.

Comment: That's really weird.  Terms is a plain `Route` so I don't even know where the redirect would be triggered.

Comment: Exactly, I have tried to find where or when it is triggered but have so far been unable to locate it. In my debugging attempt, I have disabled `PrivateRoutes`, `if (localStorage.jwtToken) {...}`, `FullPageLayout` as well as working with `initialState` but so far no success. I have to perhaps first find where the redirect to `index` is triggered. Any suggestions in terms of debugging?

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with with your server configuration rather than your code.  It probably redirects all unknown paths to the root.

Comment: Thanks Linda, I managed to find out where the problem was coming from. See my new comment. Essentially for my plain routes even though I was not using the `navbarComponent`, it was still being loaded and checked for the user to be defined and if not, it was returning me to the `index` page.

Answer (score 1):

So after some debugging, I realised that my problem is coming from `AppPages` and the line with `{ navbarComponent }`. This navbar is used with the `PrivateRoute` and requires the user to be defined. When the user is unauthenticated, although this will not technically render for plain routes, it is still processed and inside this `navbar` is a condition that if the user is undefined, will return to the `index` page.